# Phonegap embed assets for web app

Tags: cordova, iphone-web-app

I'm trying to embed my elements into the app to make it faster. But when I cal an image with

```
<img src='file:///android_asset/www/img/logo.png'  />
```

I have an error : "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/images/logo.png" "

The HTML source comes from the server. But I really think I should emebed my CSS, JS and images into the app...

How can you go around that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this entire HTML page coming from the server or are you just fetching part of the markup from the server? i.e. single page app v/s multipage app. If it is a single page app you can references resources with just the path, without the file:// scheme

Comment: Ahh! I missed this part `HTML source comes from the server`